# Can I use Laravel JSON Where Clauses with MariaDB 10.2.16 LongText column?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.6

I tried to add a json column to my database by using phpMyAdmin

but Unfortunately, phpMyAdmin converts the json column to Longtext type

So, I'm asking about the ability to use the JSON Where Clauses with this type

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Well from the documentation, MariaDB is not listed in the supported DB systems:Laravel also supports querying JSON column types on databases that provide support for JSON column types. Currently, this includes MySQL 5.7, PostgreSQL, SQL Server 2016, and SQLite 3.9.0 (with the JSON1 extension)

Comment: Laravel 5.8 will support JSON queries on MariaDB: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use those queries on non-JSON data types in MariaDB. And as of 10.2, it doesn't officially support it.

You can use the [JSON helper functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/) to query against data (ie: `where JSON_CONTAINS(...)` and others.

You can also create columns that are extracted values from the JSON data using [Virtual Columns](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/putting-virtual-columns-good-use)

Here's a [good post](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102) with much more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply

Comment: I'm going to check all these URLs

Comment: Another question please, I'm using RunCloud service to manage my Ubuntu server, but they offers a good tool to manage MariaDB databases, But still I can install mysql engine in my server, does it worth? to get all benefits from using the laravel json queries